# Watch $route.params.id does not trigger re-render of Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have a `Post` component which displays user posts. The URL/Route to get to a post is like:

`http://localhost:8080/123-todays-bike-ride` with `123` being the `PostID` param in the route.

In my `Post.vue` component I have the following code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{Post.PostTitle}}</h1>
        <p>{{Post.Content}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "Post",
        watch:{
            '$route.params.PostID': function() {
                    this.getPost(); // does not seem to be triggered?
                }
        },
        computed:
            {
                Post() {
                    return this.$store.getters.getPost
                }
            },
        serverPrefetch() {
            return this.getPost();  // to do with SSR
        },
        mounted() {
            if (this.Post == null || !this.Post.length) {
                this.getPost();
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getPost() {
                return this.$store.dispatch('loadPost', {PostID: this.$route.params.PostID})

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that even if I navigate from `http://localhost:8080/123-todays-bike-ride` to say `http://localhost:8080/999-swimming` then the URL in the browser address bar changes but the content of the `Post` view does not change – it remains with the same content as the `123-todays-bike-ride` post.

Clearly the `watch: { '$route.params.PostID'...` bit is not working, but why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try and make it watch deep:

```
   watch: {
    "$route.params.PostID": {
      handler: function(value) {
        console.log(value);
      },
      deep: true,
      immediate: true,
    },
  },
```

---

Also another way of doing this by re-rendering a component without using `watch:`

by adding `:key="$route.params.PostID"` to the Post component like:

inside `ParentComponent.vue`

```
<template>
    <Post :key="$route.params.PostID" />
</template>
```

Comment: there is called a smart watcher

Comment: that worked! where is this stuff in the docs? The only thing I found on `watch` was in https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html which was no help whatsoever. Really struggling to learn Vue at this rate

Comment: You can read about deep watch here: https://michaelnthiessen.com/how-to-watch-nested-data-vue/. VueJS bloggers have done a better job than the official docs.